# How to make an object unique across the Schema's array attributes in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a To-do Schema:

```
const todoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
  completed: [{
    task_id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'task'
    }
  }],
  unfinished: [{
    task_id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'task'
    }
  }],
  notstarted: [{
    task_id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'task'
    }
  }]
});
```

I want a task to be unique across the 3 arrays, and when a user changes a task's status, I would like to be able to move it from an array to another wihout having to manually look through each one, remove it from it and add it to the right one, especially since I have many different arrays to look in in my case.

How can I do that please?

Answer (score 0):

in your case study, it says you want to store Task object Ids inside To-do model's array right?  so you don't need to have unique ids. just the id from Task. then when a task is created push it to not started array then when it started remove it from not started and push it to unfinished array ans so on that's it

Comment: In other words, I need the "completed, unfinished, not started" arrays to be mutually disjoint. The problem is that a user wouldn't always move tasks in that order, they might have made a mistake, or dropped a task and had to move it back from finished to unfinished etc. and ince I don't know the order, I'll have to search through each array individually.